# Resize BufferedImage without Scaling image

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to upgrade a Java Swing Application, and I have a part where I manipulate some small icons I am drawing in my application as BufferedImages. I want a few specific icons at certain circumstances to display an additional triangle symbol on top. The symbol+triangle is considered after the addition as a simple symbol and I thought it would be easier to do if I could resize the BufferedImage I have already and draw on top. But I have not been able to do so. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can create a new `BufferedImage` get its graphic and use the [drawImage(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) to scale the original image.

Comment: Worked perfectly, just a little fiddling more to get it in place. Thanks a lot!